# selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable after switching the frame

Tags: python, selenium

I want to automate filling google forms with the images in google drive so I am using python with selenium.

The first image I can automate, but I got the error when I repeated the same process for the second image.

I created a sample google form to test.
https://forms.gle/fZ439KckkbpNU68v5

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('x path to first add file button').click()
frame= driver.find_element_by_class_name('picker-frame')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
*the first time it is working time*

driver.switch_to_default_content()

time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath to secondadd file button').click()
frame= driver.find_element_by_class_name('picker-frame')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
*after this, it causes an error*
```

I could not use the send_keys() method because this is button type.

[image]

[image]

Full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import random,time

option=webdriver.ChromeOptions()

driver = webdriver.Chrome("path to chrome driver")

driver.get("https://forms.gle/RvBYTZG5xuWoD8QA7")

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]').send_keys("gmail")

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierNext"]/div/button').click()
time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys("password")

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwordNext"]/div/button').click()

time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/span').click()

frame1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('picker-frame')

driver.switch_to.frame(frame1)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id=":6"]').click()

time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id=":1a.docs.0.1oe7tESa9uNnUC75FdYuqzPtPbLYz7QFi"]/div[2]').click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="picker:ap:2"]').click()

driver.switch_to_default_content()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]').click()

frame2 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('picker-frame')

driver.switch_to.frame(frame2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id=":6"]').click()

time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Can you share your full code here with login steps?

Comment: login works just fine, I managed to trick google to allow login in selenium. The problem after switching the frame. I edited with full code. @QualityMatters

Comment: For me , login doesn't work. Can't help.

Comment: @QualityMatters create a new Gmail account when running the selenium, after that, you can use the account to log in.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess since no HTML was provided but maybe the location in the iframe of the element isnt correct since if you give it the global iframe path it want work i suggest to check if the button has a specifique i frame and switch to that iframe and give it the path in that one.
Or the element path isn't unique that makes problems too.

Comment: I did a test to see that too by automating on the second button first, as a result, it works, but the first button does not work.

Comment: yeah i had the same probleme as i said point on the buttons inspect the button and you will find an iframe refresh the page and this will show #document take that path and then point on the iframe that contained #document not the global one

Answer (score 0):

I think you are typing it wrongly. You should try this code.
`driver.switch_to.default_content()`

Comment: I see no difference between the two methods.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to put the refresh after switching the frame. Without having to use the switch_to_default_content() at all.

```
driver.refresh()
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

It works.